# How to make header of a table "draggable"

Tags: jquery

I have a table. The top row has 2 columns - "header" and "close" button. I can make the entire table "draggable". How can I make the "header" to be the only element that user can drag in order to move the entire table around?

UPDATED: As tagged, I need to use jQuery. This is what's not working:

```
$(tblElement).draggable({ handle: "tdDialogHeader" });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Posting code that doesn't work will help people answer your question and show that you've attempted something

Comment: That's the thing: I can't even find anything that would resemble what I need in jQuery docs. That table is a "dialog" that has a "header" with some title. I'd like to be able to move that dialog around by dragging it by its header. Very common scenario, can't find a solution

Comment: he's asking how you made the table "draggable" in the first place. It's a fairly non-trivial task. Like saying "I built a car this morning, how do I make the trunk close".

Comment: @Sinetheta: Then it's too broad for an SO question.

Comment: @Tomalak. This is a very common use of drag-n-drop functionality. I can name you how to achieve this in several other frameworks. I can write this myself. But I need to use jQuery. So, I don't understand why it is too broad if after several minutes no one can give me a direct answer? Seems a normal question to me.

Comment: @Sinetheta. No, I don't ask how to make the entire table draggable. I ask how to move that entire table by only dragging its header. Exactly as you can drag any Windows or Mac window, dialog, etc.

Comment: @Simon: You may be confused. If after several minutes no-one has given you a direct answer then that is _more_, not less, evidence that your question is too broad.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal. I see your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the solution suggested by Sinetheta doesn't work for you, that means your table doesn't have "tHead" tag as its header. jQuery is not great with tables, especially if they are malformed. Replace the "TR" tag of the first row in your table with "tHead" and try the Sinetheta's code. Should work.

Comment: Replaced the TR with THEAD in the first row. Worked. THANK YOU!

Comment: always cool when a comment is posted as an "answer" AND get's tagged as the solution

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you're using the jQuery UI. Then you're looking for the ["handle" option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle).

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ handle: "thead" });
```

Comment: This still allows moving the table by dragging any of its elements

Comment: God damn! Just a bit more and my mind could blow. Thanks good man!)